# Which MX server should I enter for my Mail to go to the mail hosting company

Tags: email, heroku, dns, mx-record

I am going to set up my application on HEROKU which does not offer mail services.

The company I am doing this for has a mail service company. The previous web host changed the MX record on their servers to point to this company.

My Domain Name Provider is Network Solutions.  Do I set up the MX records on Network Solutions to point to  the Mail service company even if the domain points to the DNS on HEROKU?

I am a NOOB and don't want to mess up the companies email. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: web and mail are two different things and can be hosted on completely different servers. so, if you don't want to mess up their mail, copy the mx records exactly as they are now (eg point them to the mail service company).

Comment: Thanks Gryphius I will do that, point to the mail server using the MX record in Network Solutions website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should point the MX record to the mail service company. You should also investigate how to setup a PTR record for your mx host that maps the IP back to your hostname. You may need to have the mail service provider do this for you. This PTR record helps in getting your domain's email through other mail servers' SPAM filter.